# Controlling container width based on content of one of the objects

Tags: html, css

I think by a fluke, this works on Chrome. How can I get the Chrome look across all browsers? Ideally the container width is set by the Chinese text and possibly the pinyin, but the rubydef wraps. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tofutim/a10xm9s5/

[image]

```
<style>
#container {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    margin: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    display: table;
}
.text {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-row;
    width:auto;
    font-size:36pt;
    line-height:115%;
    background: #ffcccc;
}
.pinyin {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccccff;
}
.rubydef {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    background: #ccffcc;
}

</style>
<p>
<div id='container'>
    <div class='pinyin'>tái bāo</div>
    <div class='text'>台胞</div>
    <div class='rubydef'>tomato is a good fruit i wish i could eat it this week</div>
</div>
```

Comment: works in opera for me. can't use firefox for some reason but I'll see what i can do.

Comment: and explorer doesn't work for almost anything, as your screenshot shows it only looking weird in explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you missing is `white-space: nowrap;` within your `text`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a10xm9s5/6/).